# Clean logs in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I made a stress test on Google App Engine and now:
Logs Stored Data
says
82.77 GBytes

How can I clean up the logs from that specific version? I tried to download with bash script but they remain.
Is there a way to configure that I don't want to store logs more than the free quota?

===============================================================================
UPDATE: the amount of money doesn't count in the daily cost .. Probably it's there just as an information ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently there is no way to delete logs for a specific version. But what you can do is to change the log retention to 0 days in the Applications Settings. That will remove your logs. Then you can change the log retention to the desired value.

Comment: Are you sure it works? Because at the moment in Application Settings I have: "1 GBytes of logs storage or 50 days of logs". But it didn't prevent to store 82 GBytes of logs ..

Comment: I tried it before (and rechecked it now) and it worked. You can try it, and if it doesn't work or if it keeps reporting a bad log size, then you could file an issue on http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list

Comment: ok thank you .. last question: how long does it take to update the report in the dashboard?

Comment: In my case took a couple of seconds, but in your case could take longer given the amount of logs.

Comment: It didn't work for me. When I change the retention to 0 days the log looks empty, but when I change the value back, the log entries reappear. It seems it's cheaper for Google to hide the logs rather than delete them.

Comment: Logs are not deleted instantly, it can take some time to delete them. How much space of log storage were you using and how much time did you wait?

Comment: I can't find log retention setting in the application settings today though